# How to add multiple strings to one index in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to add a first an last name to **one** index of a mutable array.

I'm loading a first and last name from the AdressBook API and I want the first and last name in an array, so I can display that later to the user.

Currently, I can log the first an last name, but when I try to add these to an array, the array stays null.

This is the code I'm using:

```
[_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName]];
NSLog(@"%@", _names); //prints 'null'

NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);//prints 'John Appleseed'
```

Why isn't my array being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure you initiated the array properly using `_names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`? You cannot add objects into an uninitialized array.

Comment: That's it. I'm officially ashamed now.